# Facebook api in python and sources to master it!

Tags: python, facebook, api

I've good enough knowledge of python and I want to use facebook python api and for that I've got all the API key and App Secret etc from the developer site. Now what I want is a good source to provide me with good knowledge how to authenticate and retrieve data like statuses etc using the Python IDLE(in win7). I searched the google but unable to reliable one! Thanx people! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use the python version of the [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk). It contains a few examples.